# Sum of numbers in a column after certain cells that would calculate how many "points" between each item

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to calculate the amount of points between each "drop" I receive from a boss in a game I play. I am looking to automate this without manually having to `=sum()` each time I receive a drop.

I'd like column F to show the sum of points between each drop on the row where the drop was received, similarly to column G.

Currently, I have a bunch of `=sum()`but my spreadsheet is getting pretty long and I'd like to automate it if possible.
[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10lS9kNPdWctHIsB5qtC0LSkhyky_1ahkV0RsY5gFwvo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(if(len(D2:D),scan(,B2:B,lambda(a,c,if(c="",,if(offset(c,-1,2)="drop",c,a+c)))),))
```

[image]

Comment: Once again, working like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change your perspective, this will be easier:

```
=if(C2=False, F1+B2, B2)
```

Use this for F2 cell (Let F1 to be zero). Then copy this for entire column.